# discord bot nested await message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Attempting to implement texas hold em poker in discord with a bot using node js.
Currently have a problem try to nest
`client.on('message', message => {`
calls. The idea behind these is that the first one looks for the !poker command, and subsequent ones listen for joining players, player bets etc.

code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const Game = require("./classes.js").Game
const Player = require("./classes.js").Player

// create a new Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// when the client is ready, run this code
// this event will only trigger one time after logging in
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

let prefix = '!';

client.on('message', message => {
    //prevent feedback loops
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}poker`)){
        //getting args
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');  
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        //converting to relevant data type
        let no_players = parseInt(args[0]);
        let money = parseInt(args[1]) 

        //initialising game object and card deck
        let game = new Game();
        game.deck = game.createDeck();

        //list to contain players (will be objects from the Player class)
        let players = [];
        //list to contain player usernames, will be used to identify if someone has already joined
        let player_users = [];

        // loop until we have enough players, as specified by the first input arguemnt
        while (players.length <= no_players){
            //now wait for a join message
            client.on('message', message => {
                //if message == join, and the player has not already joined
                if (message.content.startsWith('join')){
                    if (!players.includes(message.author.username)){
                        let newPlayer = new Player(message.author.username,money);
                        players.push(newPlayer);
                        player_users.push(message.author.username);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        //debugging purposes
        console.log(players)
    }  
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}hands`)){
        message.channel.send("Here are the poker hands", {files: ["poker-hand-rankings-mobile.png"]});
    }
    
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

The command syntax in discord will look like `!poker {number of players} {betting money for each player}`
Other functionality in create decks etc works fine.

When I run in the debugger it doesnt seem to enter the second client.on code block, and I recieve this error upon running `FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Not sure if my overall approach is flawed here, i.e. discord.js cant have two processes waiting for messages running at the same time. Or if there is variable overlap between defining message.

Considering scrapping and moving to python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should NEVER nest any events. This will lead to memory leaks as is the case here. Use message listeners, such as [TextChannel#awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

Comment: @Elitezen, thanks for the tip, will implement this